# What does ds.Tables[0].Select() represents

Tags: c#, asp.net

What dr gets here.

```
DataRow[] dr = objds.Tables[0].Select("ProcessName = '" + tnProcName.Text + "'");
```

I am getting dr{System.Data.DataRow[4]} and not the line individually.

In dr now consists of list of rows.How can i compare the column present in data row.

Comment: `DataTable.Select()` gets you all `DataRow` objects that match specified criteria. What did you expect to get?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `DataTable.Select` do exactly? Did you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first?

Comment: Actually i want to get a list of processes and bind them to a Tree Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns an array of DataRow that match the selection criteria expressed by the first parameter of the Select method

```
DataRow[] dr = objds.Tables[0].Select("ProcessName = '" + tnProcName.Text + "'");
foreach(DataRow r in dr)
{
   string procName = r["ProcessName"].ToString();
   treeView1.Nodes.Add(procName);

}
```

Select has four overloads to fine tune the results

```
DataTable.Select(); // return all (same as dataTable.Rows)
DataTable.Select(filter); //The above one
DataTable.Select(filter, sort) //Filtered and/or sorted
DataTable.Select(filter, sort, rowstate) // Filtered and/or sorted and/or in a particular state
```

[Here the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Probably it is not your case, but keep in mind that if the expression parameter has a single quote then you need to double it to avoid a syntax error when the expression is evaluated

```
DataRow[] dr = objds.Tables[0].Select("ProcessName = '" + 
               tnProcName.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'");
```

Comment: dr now consists of list of rows.How can i compare the column present in data row.

Comment: Every DataRow in the array could be accessed using the indexer or a foreach loop as shown above, the combination of Row/Column is addressed from the single row using the index of the column or its name

Answer (score 0):

.Select will return the Datarows array with filtered values "ProcessName = '" + tnProcName.Text + "'"