# Issue with a value exist in a Datatable c#

Tags: c#

I have a Priority column in which it contains 3 values **"Low","Normal","High"** i need to check if a given value exist in a table . If it doesn't contain those 3 values it should throw error message as value not found . I have tried following method but my issue is if i give value as `Normal` it will only check first value(i.e. Low)and come out of loop and show error message.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(updatetaskinfo.Priority))
        {
          DataSet _dataSet = um.GetPriority();
           foreach (DataRow _row in _dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
             {
               if (_row["priority_name"].ToString() == updatetaskinfo.Priority)
                 {
                    xcmTaskinfo.Priority = _row["priority_shortname"].ToString();
                    break;
                 }
                 else
                   {
                      throw new DataManagementException("Priority is not valid");
                   }
             }
        }
```

Comment: Why you want to loop. .simply check it have values by DataTable.Select(); ex., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774887/what-does-ds-tables0-select-represents

Comment: If you really want to use a loop here, declare a `bool` variable before the loop and set it to `false`, then in you loop set it to `true` whenever the value is found. Below your loop, check that variable and act accordingly

Comment: @Rafalon can you show how to do that ....

Comment: `bool isFound = false; foreach(var x in y) { if(x == z) { isFound = true; break; } } if(!isFound) { throw new WhateverException(""); }`

Comment: @Rafalon thank you it worked add this to answer i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use a loop here,

- declare a `bool` variable before the loop and set it to `false`
- in you loop set it to `true` whenever the value is found (optionally `break` out of the loop if you don't want to keep looping when you already found the value)
- below your loop, check that variable and act accordingly

Something like:

```
bool isFound = false;
foreach(var x in y)
{
    if(x == z)
    {
        isFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!isFound)
{
    throw new WhateverException("");
}
```